# Having Trouble Retrieving MP3 files from Cache Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am having issues gathering the data downloaded and into a local directory "directory". Which then I can play with local media player code within the app.

I've read online guides, and checked out the android documentation. I get that there is a way, but it's not making sense. I'm not asking for it to be a word for word, but maybe a better resource online would help me better understand how to handle the files once they are downloaded.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Meglio on 3/15/17.
 */

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private List<Item_Sermon> itemsList;
    public File localFile = null;
    public Context context;
    public Uri localFilePath;

    private FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    private StorageReference url;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        //Create Variables
        private TextView mTimeStamp;
        private TextView mTitle;
        private ImageButton mDownloadButton;
        private ImageButton mMediaPlay;
        private ProgressBar mProgress;

        private MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            // Setup Views and initiate them.
            mTimeStamp = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.item_textview_timestamp);
            mTitle = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.item_textview_title);
            mDownloadButton = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.item_button_download);
            mMediaPlay = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.item_button_play);
            mProgress = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.loadingPanel);
        }
    }

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<Item_Sermon> itemsList) {
        this.itemsList = itemsList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.sermon_list_item, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Item_Sermon item = itemsList.get(position);
        //Create holders example below
        //Convert long timestamp to string
        String dateString = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a").format(new Date(item.getTimestamp()));
        holder.mTimeStamp.setText(dateString);
        holder.mTitle.setText(item.getTitle());

        //setup download button
        holder.mDownloadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View view) {
                Log.d("Adapter", "Download Button was clicked!");
                loading(holder);
                String mFilePath = item.getFilePath();
                try {
                    localFile = File.createTempFile("audio", "mp3");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                url = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(mFilePath);
                url.getFile(localFile)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                // Successfully downloaded data to local file
                                loadingComplete(holder);
                                Log.i("Adapter","Download Complete!");
                                Log.i("Adapter", "Gathering file..");
                               // How do I cache the files in it's own local
                               // local directory??
                               // android online guides aren't helping       
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        // Handle failed download
                        loadingFailed(holder);
                        Log.e("Adapter","Download Failed");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        holder.mMediaPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Play the audio file with the local media player or create one.
            }
        });
        }


    private void loadingComplete(final MyViewHolder holder){
        holder.mDownloadButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    private void loading(final MyViewHolder holder){
        holder.mDownloadButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.mProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    private void loadingFailed(final MyViewHolder holder){
        holder.mDownloadButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemsList.size();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share the error or other unexpected behavior please? Not really sure what's broken and can't run the code myself.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is now access the cached file so that I can play it in the next "audio_detail" activity. How would I go about accessing the file??

Comment: Looks like you created a temporary file called "audio.mp3" so I assume there's a file in `/tmp/audio.mp3` that you can access.

Comment: Ah, I thought that was just the type. I hadn't realized that, that was a namespace I can use my POJO to get the name of the file. However, my question still remains of being able to get the file and move it to the apps folder internally so that I can pull from there within the app.